# How can I find the beta progress for the site?

Tags: support, site-evaluation

I know this site is in Beta, in area 51 they have a nice graphic that illustrates how far along a site is based on the various metrics.  What are the metrics to get out of beta and how are we doing?

Comment: Biggest issue I see right now is that there are only two users over 20k, and only one of those is active. Bamboo's almost there, but I'm not sure how much she'd use her privileges, going on how she's using them now. There really aren't many higher rep active users.

Comment: Is that one of the metrics for a full site?  Many users over 20k?

Comment: Not sure, but in a graduated site you don't have all your privileges until 20k, vs. 4k in a beta. So there would be very few users with full moderation privileges.

Comment: Also, http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/546?m=16059959#16059959